# Which has higher priority between unsaturated ring and unsaturated chain in the nomenclature of organic compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, ethers

According to the IUPAC rules of nomenclature, alkenes have higher priority over rings but what if the ring also contains a double or a triple bond?

For eg:

[image: Organic compound]

Is this compound going to be named as 1-(2-chlorocycloprop-2-enoxy)propene or 1-chloro-3-propenoxycyclopropene?

Comment: "According to the IUPAC rules of nomenclature, alkenes have higher priority over rings" – where did you find this rule? It's not in the current IUPAC recommendations.

Comment: @Loong Check this nomenclature for eg https://images.app.goo.gl/C4EEzNMs5zoy2BmV6

Comment: or this one https://images.app.goo.gl/FhmRDtSUG8wZ72LY7 they clearly exhibit that rings have lesser priority than alkenes (in my question I asked about the unsaturated rings)

Comment: Both examples "1,2-dicyclopropylethene" and "2-cyclopropylpropene" are not preferred IUPAC names.

Comment: I'm unaware then but in all my books the nomenclatures are done in a similar way.

Comment: for eg:- in the book Modern's ABC of chemistry Pg-1195 it is clearly mentioned that : if the side chain contains multiple bond or a functional group the alicyclic ring is treated as the substituent irrespective of the size of the ring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The name given by ChemDraw is: **(*E*)-1-chloro-3-(prop-1-en-1-yloxy)cycloprop-1-ene**.

**The ring is determined to be the parent structure.**  This is rationalised in the 2013 edition of the IUPAC Blue Book on organic nomenclature by the following rules (pg 451):

> **P-44.1.2.2** Systems composed of rings and chains (exclusive of linear phanes)
>
> Two methods are recognized to name systems composed of rings and chains (exclusive of linear phanes).
>
> (1) Within the same class, **a ring or ring system has seniority over a chain.** When a ring and a chain contain the same senior element, the ring is chosen as parent.  Rings and chains are chosen regardless of their degree of hydrogenation.  As a consequence, this approach prefers the choice of a ring over a chain in systems composed of cyclic and acyclic hydrocarbons
>
> (2) The context may favor the ring or the chain, so that, for example, substituents may be treated alike or **an unsaturated a cyclic structure may be recognised**, or the one chosen has the greater number of skeletal atoms in the ring or in the principal chain of the acyclic structure.

So either the chain or ring **may** be used as the parent for the name, but the ring will define the **preferred IUPAC name**.

The preference of ring over chain is further clarified in the following rule (pg 596):

> **P-52.2.8** Selection between a ring and a chain as parent hydride
>
> Within the same heteroatom class and for tha same number of characteristic groups cited as the principal characteristic group, **a ring is always selected as the parent hydride to construct a prefered IUPAC name.** *In general nomenclature*, a ring or a chain can be a parent hydride (see P-44.1.2.2).

All emphasis added.